# Kernel 4.4.1-1 fails to boot - root volume "does not exist" - 3.10.0.327 and 4.3.3-1 both continue to boot fine

Tags: linux-kernel, redhat-enterprise-linux, dracut

I'm trying to install and boot kernel-ml (currently 4.4.1-1) on RHEL 7.2 following the instructions here: http://linuxg.net/install-kernel-4-x-on-enterprise-linux-7-centos-7-and-rhel-7/

Install works fine and on reboot I can choose the new kernel from the grub menu - however it fails midway through booting up.

When it fails, I can see multiple instances of the following:

```
dracut-initqueue[632]: Warning: dracut-initqueue timeout - starting timeout scripts
```

Followed by this:

```
dracut-initqueue[632]: Warning: Could not boot.
dracut-initqueue[632]: Warning: /dev/mapper/vg_root-lv_root does not exist
dracut-initqueue[632]: Warning: /dev/vg_root/lv_root does not exist
Starting Dracut emergency shell...
```

I can still boot into the previously working old kernel, and to another 4.x (4.3.3-1) without issue, but 4.4.1-1 fails at this point every time.  SO far I've tried the following with no success (some of the iseda come from https://askubuntu.com/questions/567730/gave-up-waiting-for-root-device-ubuntu-vg-root-doesnt-exist which looked like a similar error):

Exiting the dracut emergency shell - boot does not progress any further

Specifying root volume by UUID in the grub config - still not found

Checking if lvm2 is installed - it is

ls /dev/mapper - all I see under here is "control"

Added all_generic_ide boot parameter - no change

Rebuilt the initramfs for the broken kernel - no change

Removed rhgb and quiet from boot params

listing disks with lvm pvdisplay / lvm lvdisplay / lvm vgdisplay - none found, blank output

I'm not sure what else I can try here or what to do next  - any pointers appreciated

Comment: Did you find a way out? I'm having exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same problem on Ubuntu, the same scenario: 4.3.3 works but 4.4.x+ does not. The same thing was happening that no drives were found at all under /dev/mapper.

In my case, the problem wasn't with lvm (although I thought that was the issue as well), but that my computer uses a NVMe solid state drive (a Dell XPS 9550). According to [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_13_%282016%29#NVM_Express_SSD), the location of the "nvm" driver was moved in between kernel 4.3 and 4.4. Some OSes have yet to update their `initramfs` to accommodate for the new location (including Arch and Ubuntu), causing the kernel to build without it.

See this bug in the Ubuntu queue: [nvm extension is not properly loaded in `initramfs`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1532146).

The Arch Wiki suggests:

> Edit your /etc/mkinitcpio.conf file:

```
...
MODULES="... nvme"
...
```

> Then update the bootloader.

```
# mkinitcpio -p linux
```

But as Ubuntu doesn't have `mkinitcpio` to fix the problem as recommended in the Arch Wiki, I loaded the `nvm` extension in `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`:

```
sudo bash -c "echo '
nvme' >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules"
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

If you have an NVM drive, you may also be running a Skylake chipset. If so, you should also download the i915 drivers and add the `i915` extension to this same file, as recommended in https://askubuntu.com/questions/717338/installing-4-4-rc7-kernel-yields-i915-module-not-available